# How can I avoid resizing of a view because of keyboard on React Native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing a React Native app. I have two view in a screen. Both of them have height property.

```
height: '50%'
```

This is my screen:

[image: screen]

This happens when I click one of the inputs:

[image: screen2]

Resizing of the map is not a problem but I want to avoid resizing of the other view. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried setting `minHeight: Dimensions.get('screen').height / 2` on the bottom View styles?

Comment: It's a good solution, at least my inputs doesn't be tiny. But with this soluition I can't see the pink button when keyboard on.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered putting both the `<View>` component inside a `<Scrollview>` component? It will be a better user experience for the user as it allows scrolling as their need and can avoid shrinking of both the components

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: You can avoid resizing by increasing both min and max properties at the same time but you must use screen units, not percentages, in this way:
flex: 0.2,
minHeight: 120,
maxHeight: 120,

You can also use the flex property at the same time to preserve the screen distribution.

Greetings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).